# How to switch from preview to record video without rebooting the camera with DirectShow

Tags: camera, record, directshow, preview, restart

I using directshow programming under C++, open the program to achieve the preview screen,and move the camera device to the correct position, then I start record video. These functions can be realized. but the problem is program switch preview from video record, will restart a camera,so I would like to asking, directshow there is no way to directly from preview switching to record

Answer (score 0):

Camera filter changes state with the filter graph, and you cannot keep the camera running while doing rebuilding of the pipeline, closing files etc.

A typical solution is a two graph design. Upstream graph is doing capture, downstream graph is doing preview or preview with recording or just recording. You keep first graph running and you stop/change second graph. There is some mechanism to connect the graph and transfer the captured frame between the graphs.

The most popular solution which is used by those who look for out of the box solution to the problem is [GDCL Bridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/).

See also:

- [Directshow Preview Only and Capture & Preview with a single Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001026/868014)
- [Directshow recording/preview problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203651/directshow-recording-preview-problem?rq=1)
- [GMFBridge How to get two previews and a capture for the same stream?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1aa3ee91-3495-4f15-a86c-d33c16d7ec32/gmfbridge-how-to-get-two-previews-and-a-capture-for-the-same-stream?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)